# Summernote + Vue2 Js only works if it's not static linked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, summernote

Hello I'm currently trying to add Summernote editor to a Vue2 Js project but I can only manage it to work if it's linked through an external URL, if I try to link the same files in the local it doesn't properly load the lib.
Error:

> vue.common.js?e881:593 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   $(...).summernote is not a function"
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
>           at src\views\Documents\EditDocument.vue
>             at src\components\Dashboard\Layout\Content.vue
>               at src\components\Dashboard\Layout\DashboardLayout.vue
>                 at src\App.vue
>                   warn @ vue.common.js?e881:593 logError @ vue.common.js?e881:1739 globalHandleError @ vue.common.js?e881:1734
>   handleError @ vue.common.js?e881:1723 callHook @
>   vue.common.js?e881:2925 insert @ vue.common.js?e881:4160
>   invokeInsertHook @ vue.common.js?e881:5962 patch @
>   vue.common.js?e881:6181 Vue._update @ vue.common.js?e881:2672
>   updateComponent @ vue.common.js?e881:2790 get @
>   vue.common.js?e881:3144 run @ vue.common.js?e881:3221
>   flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.common.js?e881:2983 (anonymous) @
>   vue.common.js?e881:1839 flushCallbacks @ vue.common.js?e881:1760
>   vue.common.js?e881:1743 TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function
>       at VueComponent.mounted (Summernote.js?f9ca:45)
>       at callHook (vue.common.js?e881:2923)
>       at Object.insert (vue.common.js?e881:4160)
>       at invokeInsertHook (vue.common.js?e881:5962)
>       at VueComponent.patch [as **patch**] (vue.common.js?e881:6181)
>       at VueComponent.Vue._update (vue.common.js?e881:2672)
>       at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.common.js?e881:2790)
>       at Watcher.get (vue.common.js?e881:3144)
>       at Watcher.run (vue.common.js?e881:3221)
>       at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.common.js?e881:2983)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="static/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="static/img/favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/font-awesome-4.4.0.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap-3.3.5.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/summernote-0.8.1.css"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title>Portal - Admin</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <!--  Fonts and icons     -->
  <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/static/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper" id="app">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/summernote.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/test.js"></script>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

If JQuery, Summernote and Bootstrap were linked through the url of CDN for the same files it would work fine (same with the CSS files on top).
More information can be provided if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: open you browser console, then check whether succeeded to load `jquery.js` and `summernote.js` at `Network tab`